# Resizing a windows form does not resize inner components

Tags: c#, winforms

I had to touch windows forms again and I am having some hard time figuring out something which should be very easy to fix.

I've got this control:

[image: Control]

which when I place in a form looks like this:

[image: Control]

The problem is that when running the form this is how the control place on it looks:

[image: Control]

I set the anchor property in all the component with the control, so I am not sure what the problem it. The control should resize its components when the form is resized but that is not happening.

Any help will be more than welcome.

Marco

Comment: A good starting point is to double-check the anchor properties on all the components, then rebuild the solution. (I've had several issues like this that turned out to just be the designer using a previously compiled version of the control).

Comment: @HighCore don´t be, because as a back-end developer I rather do some work with Windows Forms then do some web related work, unless of course I am allowed to use Silverlight :)

Comment: @Marco web is another story in and of itself, but winforms is a dinosaur, and it's completely useless when you compare it to current XAML based technologies (I.E WPF)

Comment: @HighCore I know exactly what you mean, but unfortunately it is not up to me to decide, and yes I am a WPF and all XAML based technologies  fan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is a weird issue. I changed the font in the form to Verdana and forgot to change it in the Control as well, and this is what was causing the issue. Maybe it has to do with the way fonts are rendered.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set `Dock` property to `Fill` on your containers.  I'm not quite sure the structure of your layout, I use TableLayout or Panels, set Dock to fill on that, so that is stretched with the main window. And inside of the container I place my components, again set to Dock where appropriate.

Comment: Maybe I did not make myself clear enough. I've set the archor property of all the components inside the control, so if I resize that control alone all component within it, the buttons, textboxes... get resized and this is what I expect, the problem is when I add that control to the form with the anchor properties set as well, and resize it, in this case the components within the control are not respecting the anchor property anymore. Thanks for your help though.